# Smooth approximation of bounded function belonging to some Sobolev space

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I need your help to answer this questions:

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and let $u\in W^{1,p}_{0} (\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. There exists $u_{n}\in C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ converging to $u$ strongly in $ W^{1,p}_{0} (\Omega)$?

If $u\in W^{1,p}_{0} (\Omega)$, with $u\geq 0$. There exists a sequence of nonnegative smooth functions $\{u_{n}\}$ converging to $u$ strongly in $ W^{1,p}_{0} (\Omega)$?

Comment: What kind of a domain is $\Omega$? What have you already tried?

Comment: $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb(R)^{n}$.

Comment: Isn't the definition of $W^{1,p}_0$ the closure of $C^\infty_0$ in the $W^{1,p}$ norm? If not, then what is your definition?

Comment: I need a bounded smooth sequence converging to u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, any function in $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ is in $L^\infty(\Omega)$ (continuous function on compact sets are bounded). Do you want the *sequence* to be bounded? In that case, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404410/sobolev-spaces-about-smooth-aproximation?noredirect=1&lq=1).

For your second question: this has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405255/about-smooth-approximation-in-a-sobolev-space?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks so much Kusma.